# AWS S3 bucket delete

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have deleted an S3 bucket but it is still visible in the AWS console. There are no objects inside the bucket and there is no bucket policy associated to it. When I try to access the bucket, I get a message that "Bucket doesn't exist". When I create a new bucket with the same name (that was deleted), I get a message that "Bucket with the same name already exists". Is there a way to resolve this issue?

[Answer]: The bucket eventually got deleted after sometime (< 24 hr). For some of the other buckets (in the same geo region), it took less than a minute. So, from a time perspective, it seems to range from few minutes to hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aws s3 is eventually consistent.

Wait for a couple of hours until you recreate. It will work later

Comment: It has been more than 6 hours. Is there a time interval specified somewhere about this?

Comment: Not that i know. But i had this issue more often. If it persists try contact customer support

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/554374/how-long-before-an-s3-bucket-can-be-created-with-same-name-after-deletion

Comment: I have gone through the link but nowhere I can see an upper time limit on the delete process.